# Make glossary with `C-c C-c`

Tags: latex, auctex

I have many documents with glossaries which I used to build using this script:

```
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
makeglossaries "$documentname"
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
makeindex -s "$documentname.ist" -o "$documentname.gls" "$documentname.glo"
pdflatex "$documentname.tex"
```

The line `pdflatex "$documentname.tex"` could probably appear less often but I thought that safe is safe.

I use AUCTeX, so I can build (and view) documents via `C-c C-c`. It builds a document and tells me when to press the combination again to run LaTeX, again. It even works when BibTeX is involved and runs that. But in the case of the documents with a glossary, it doesn't build the glossaries. How can this be achieved?

Can you make it so `C-c C-c` calls itself until (inclusive) the PDF is opened? For one document, I have to press it 8 times (8 times `C-c C-c`, not 8 times `C-c`) which gets quite tiresome.

Comment: Maybe set it up so C-c C-c calls latexmk instead.

Comment: @JohnKitchin Unfortunately, I'm given documents which don't compile via `latexmk` (tested it via the `latexmk` command on the command line). Furthermore, this doesn't resolve the glossary problem.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries. Why don't your documents compile via latexmk?

Comment: @UTF-8 the easier solution is to ask the author of `glossaries` package to issue a warning in the log when it's necessary to run a program like `makeglossaries`.  AUCTeX would be able to catch that warning and run the program.

Comment: @giordano "AUCTeX would be able to catch that warning and run the program." Wouldn't this require a change in AUCTeX so that after catching the (as of yet nonexistent) warning, AUCTeX runs `makeglossaries`? So I'd first have to ask the maintainers of `glossaries` to include the warning and then ask the maintainers of AUCTeX to handle the warning.

Comment: Correct.  We have first to know what the message is, in order to catch it ;-)

Comment: There are a lot AUCTeX users and `glossaries` is a pretty commonly used LaTeX package, so I don't think I'm the first one to run into this problem. I'd think this is either handled or there's a very good reason why it isn't. But then, again, there really doesn't appear to be a warning that you should run `glossaries` in `pdflatex`'s output and running `makeglossaries` is pretty easy. AUCTeX runs `makeindex` and running that is far more difficult.

Comment: Actually, it was requested to add `makeglossaries` only last November: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24952  and you're the first one to ask for an autodetection :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to use `latexmk` and to let it know:

- about the extensions of the files it has to check,
- what to do if these files change.

That may be done in a `.latexmkrc` configuration file, e.g. in your root folder, containing something like this (`Perl` syntax):

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries');
sub makeglossaries{
    system( "makeglossaries \"$_[0]\"" );
}
```

Comment: The problem with using `latexmk` is that some documents I don't really control (I only make small fixes) can't be built using `latexmk`. If I were to substitute my built shortcut, I'd have to have a second one for building those documents and always had to remember which kind of document I'm building.

Comment: @UTF-8 Whether running `latexmk` or not on a per document basis should be possible with AUCTeX's "Local Variables".